# How to add a new field using XSL Style sheet rule

Tags: java, xml, xslt-2.0

Below are few fields in XML:

```
<dynamicField name="*_f" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_d" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_p" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_c" type="currency" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I want to add a new dynamic field similar to above fields but with different attribute values using XSL rule, Please suggest.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Please see below:

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <!--New dynamicField Added  -->
    <xsl:template match="dynamicField[last()]">

        <xsl:copy>   
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/>       
        </xsl:copy>
        <dynamicField name="*pricingInfo" type="String" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    </xsl:template>
<!-- End of dynamicField -->
</xsl:transform>
```